# Clusters features median values using Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

While working on a dataset, I used k-means clustering and I want to explore the median values of the features/variables.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Monetary': rfm_m_log,'Recency': rfm_r_log,'Frequency': rfm_f_log})
matrix = data.as_matrix()    
kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters = 2, n_init=30)
kmeans.fit(matrix)
clusters_customers = kmeans.predict(matrix)
```

How to print the **median values** of Monetary, Recency and Frequency in each cluster? (Cluster 1 and Cluster 2)

Comment: Could the cluster centroid be useful rather than the median value?

Comment: Yes it can be useful

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by slicing the data-frame according to the actual classifications:

```
# class 0 median of the Monetary column
data.iloc[np.argwhere(clusters_customers == 0).ravel()]['Monetary'].median()

# class 1 median of the Monetary column
data.iloc[np.argwhere(clusters_customers == 1).ravel()]['Monetary'].median()
```